# Which Romance languages have reflexes of the Latin nominative in nouns?

Tags: historical-linguistics, list-of-languages, latin, romance-languages, romanian

It is generally accepted that the nominal forms in the Romance languages represent reflexes of the Latin *accusative* rather than the *nominative*. (This is even true for those languages that have masculine plurals in *-i*, which is actually a regular reflex of *-os*.)

However, I'm aware of exactly one word in Romanian which is only explicable as a survival of the Latin nominative:

> *om*: "man (sg)" < Latin *homo*
>
> *oameni*: "men (pl)" < Latin *homines*

(The hypothetical, unattested Romanian reflex of Latin acc. *hominem* would be **oamene*.)

Is there any other similar reflex in other Romance languages that reflects the Latin nominative? Is there evidence for the survival of the Latin nominative into Proto-Romance in any systematic way (outside of the pronouns)?

Comment: French *loi* and *roi*?

Comment: @Timwi, I'm pretty sure that those are regular reflexes of *lege(m) *rege(m).

Comment: @JSBngs: That is correct.

Comment: Just curious, why do they generally use the accusative instead of the nominative?

Comment: Are you sure that the Romanian example comes from the nominative? Seems to me that it could be a later "correction" to avoid confusion with neuter and feminine plurals ending in -e...

Comment: @E.C., but there are other Romanian masculine nouns ending in -e: *soare, frate*, etc. I doubt that disambiguation from the neuter/feminine plural is the reason.

Comment: I didn't know that -i was a reflex of the accusative, that is interesting. I always thought it was the nominative. Anywhere (easily accessible) I can read more about this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Apparently, many subjective and objective (*cas régime*) forms of words were still used in Middle French, at least into the late Middles Ages, if you go through the etymologies of French words. Here are some examples of words in modern French that are reflexes of the Latin nominative, from the *[Centre National de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/fils)*:

French *on*:

> ... Du lat. **homo**, cas **suj**. du subst. signifiant «homme», développé en position proclitique, et qui, à basse époque, est relevé dans qq. ex. comme suj. indéterm., emploi aboutissant à sa fonction de pron. indéf.: Peregr. Aether. 13, 1: *"ubi homo desiderium suum compleri videt"*

French *fils*, "son":

> ... Du lat. class. **filius** « fils, enfant »; « descendants » en b. lat. La forme actuelle représente l'anc. cas **sujet** conservé en raison de son emploi fréq. comme vocatif et prob. aussi pour éviter la confusion avec *fil.*

A similar cross-pollination from the vocative occurred with French *soeur*, "sister" (the Old-French oblique case *seror* falling out of use):

> Du lat. **soror** « sœur ». L'a. fr. avait les formes *suer,* cas suj., et *seror,* avec différentes var., cas régime issu de l'acc. *sororem*, très tôt **le cas suj. devint le plus usuel** à cause de son utilisation fréq. au vocatif.

Another good candidate is *corps* (OFr. *cors*); the nominative is not mentioned as such, but, the word being neuter in Latin, nominative and accusative were identical in form, so it would seem likely for that form to be used rather than some declined form.

> ... Du lat. class. **corpus**, attesté aux sens de base A 1, 2, 3, B 1; sens C en lat. class., repris en fr. surtout au xvie s.; le sens D est également latin; ...

There's also *croix* and *champs*, but those probably come from plurals, in which nominative and accusative are formally identical.

Italian *uomo* (pl. *uomini*) appears to come from the nominative *homo* too. The *[Vocabolario Etimologico della Lingua Italiana](http://www.etimo.it/?term=uomo)* by Pianigiani is not entirely clear; lacking further knowledge about the phonology of that time and a reliable source, we cannot be absolutely certain that the word wasn't shortened from *huomino*, or something like that. The same applies to Provençal *hom*.

[This Spanish etymological-dictionary website](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?luz) says *hombre* comes from *hominem* but *luz, paz, voz, cruz* from *lux, pax, vox, crux*; however, I would not trust this dictionary: it sounds rather amateurish all over. I couldn't find any good, relatively modern etymological dictionary for Spanish.

---

**Update:** This quotation from [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9gime_%28cas%29) lists more examples for French:

> La forme unique du français moderne dérive le plus souvent du cas régime. Il y a cependant un certain nombre d'exceptions où **c'est le cas sujet qui a survécu**, concernant **les noms de personnes** : ex. *prestre / provoire* (« prêtre »), *ancestre / ancessor* (« ancêtre »), *traïtre / traïtor* (« traître »), *suer / seror* (« sœur ») et de nombreux prénoms. Dans quelques cas, le cas sujet et le cas régime se sont tous deux maintenus dans la langue moderne, parfois avec des sens différents : c'est le cas pour *gars / garçon, copain / compagnon, sire / seigneur, pâtre / pasteur, nonne / nonnain* et *pute / putain.* **[The first word of each pair is the Old-French nominatif.]**

A few more French examples:

*Moindre*, and many other nominals on *-dre*:

> Anc. **cas suj.**, issu du nomin. lat. *minor*, compar. de *parvus* «petit en taille, nombre, quantité, valeur, âge, rang, condition, importance», le cas régime étant *meneur* issu de l'acc. *minorem*, v. *mineur*. Dès la fin du xiie s. *mendre* fut employé au cas régime sing., puis aux cas suj. et régime plur., évinçant *meneur*.

*Gindre*:

> Anc. **cas suj.**, issu du lat. *junior* **nomin**., compar. de l'adj. *juvenis* « jeune ».

Probably *queux*:

> *Étymol. et Hist.* Ca 1100 *cous* cas régime plur. (Roland, éd. J. Bédier, 1817); ca 1165 *keu* cas suj. plur. (Guillaume d'Angleterre, éd. M. Wilmotte, 1818); 1174-76 *coeu* cas régime sing.; *keus* **cas suj. sing.** (Guernes de Pont-Ste-Maxence, St Thomas, éd. E. Walberg, 1291; 1292); fin xiies. *princes queurs de la coisine* (Prophéties de David, 69 ds T.-L.); ca 1280 *Li maistre ques* (Merveilles de Rigomer, 7684, ibid.). Du lat. *coquus* « cuisinier », devenu *cocus*.

*Maire*, from a substantivised nominative adjective (and probably many pure nouns on *-air(e)* that come from Latin *-ator*):

> A substantivation de l'anc. adj. *maire* «plus grand» ca 1165 (Benoît de Sainte-Maure, Troie, éd. L. Constans, 6031), issu du **nominatif** lat. *major*, comparatif de *magnus* «grand», v. *majeur*.

---

If you Google for `site:cnrtl.fr/etymologie/ "cas suj."|nominatif|nomin`, you will probably find a whole lot more (though most of those Google hits are not it).

Answer (score 7):

Re 'survival of the Latin nominative into Proto-Romance' - It survives into Old French, which had a [two-case system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_French#Nouns) until about the twelfth century.

So for a standard second-declension noun *vicinus* "neighbor":

```
Nom. Sg. _li voisins_ < VICINUS  Nom. Pl. _li voisin_   < VICINI
Obl. Sg. _le voisin_  < VICINUM  Obl. Pl. _les voisins_ < VICINOS
```

A sample remnant of the third declension, from *soror* "sister":

```
Nom. Sg. _la suer_  < SOROR      Nom. Pl. _les serors_  < SORORES
Obl. Sg. _la seror_ < SOROREM    Obl. Pl. _les serors_  < SORORES
```

Of course there are several innovations and Old French doesn't preserve the Latin declensions perfectly, but the original forms are retained in several declension types.

The Wikipedia article linked has a lot of example declensions, many of which appear to be sourced from Kibler's *An Introduction to Old French*.

Answer (score 3):

In Spanish there's *Dios*, which I'm pretty sure is a continuation of the nominative. Also, I want to say that *Carlos* is from the nominative form *Carolus*. And of course there's *Jesus*.

Comment: Not sure about *Carlos*, but *Dios* and *Jesús* are both biblical, and thus likely to have been copied wholesale from Latin without intervening sound changes.

Comment: I get what you're saying about Jesus (Hell, German used some of the Latin inflections of Jesus for a while), but I disagree about dios, as it's the general term for a deity; i.e. it's the word for god as well as God, so to speak. Also, the forms definitely based on *deus* are only found in Spanish & Portuguese, with Catalan *deu*, Friulian *diu*, and French *dieu* clearly coming from the accusative *deum*. My guess is that god, generally being "active" would most often be subject of a sentence, and might have contributed to the survival of the nominative form. Just my $0.02 of speculation.

Comment: I'd put it down to the fact that the word was said frequently in prayers in Latin, rather than everyday speech.

Answer (score 2):

On a recent trip to Italy I noticed that the men's restrooms say "Uomini" rather than "Uomi" as I would have naively expected. I don't know much Italian so there could be more.

I'm not aware of any examples of this phenomenon in Spanish.

Comment: The Italian example suggests that *homo/homines* is common to Eastern Romance, at least. But are there any other examples?

Comment: This is actually pretty general - plurals in Italian come from nominative in all cases as far as I am aware.

Comment: @Eleshar: Actually, as far as I know that is disputed. While the feminine plural "e" could come from Latin "ae", it also could come from "as" with vocalization of word-final "s" to [i] and subsequent monophthongization of "ai" to "e". See Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_plurals#Origin_of_vocalic_plurals

Answer (score 1):

In French:

- the word meaning field `champs` comes from `campus` nominative rather than `campum` accusative
- I suppose the word `republique` comes from `res publica` nominative rather than `rem publicam` accusative.